# Export object + skeleton from blender to Threejs and move bones manually

Tags: javascript, c++, three.js, blender

**What I need:**
A) create Human mesh with a skeleton in blender (2.69)
B) export in json with blender plugin
C) create Threejs app and move mesh manually editing bones position and rotation (quaternion). Data come from sensor a like kinect.

**What I do:**
A) done: all the bones have roll at 0°.
B) done: I export checking "Vertices", "Faces", "Bones", "Skinning", "Materials",  "Colors", "All mesh".
C) done: I create mesh loading json:

```
  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
  loader.load("../skeleton.js", function(geometry, materials) {
    materials[0].skinning = true;
    callback(new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, materials[0]));
  });
```

And then add mesh in scene.

I tried with ALL the possible configuration, but while "torso", "neck" and "head"  seem to work well, other joints make the mesh  deformed.

Has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: Make sure to apply the scale and rotation of the rig in blender. I did this, and it fixed my similar problem with makehuman nightly. It ruined my animations in blender however :(